# How to write most efficient way to add a value for an column in dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame `df` consisting of a  2 columns(word and meaning/definition of that word). I want to use the `Collections.Counter` object for each definition of a word and count the frequency of words occurring in the definition in the most pythonic way possible.

The traditional approach would be to iterate over the data frame using the `iterrows()` methods and do the computations.

Sample output

```html
<table style="height: 59px;" border="True" width="340">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Word</td>
      <td>Meaning</td>
      <td>Word Freq</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Array</td>
      <td>collection of homogeneous datatype</td>
      <td>{'collection':1,'of':1....}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `df` has two columns `'word'` and `'definition'`, then you simply use the `.map` method with `Counter` on the `definition` series after splitting on space.  Then sum the result.

```
from collections import Counter

def_counts = df.definition.map(lambda x: Counter(x.split()))
all_counts = def_counts.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks James .. your suggestion helped  a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would take advantage of Pandas `str` accessor methods and do this

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(df.definition.str.cat(sep=' ').split())
```

Some Test data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['some', 'words', 'yes'], 'definition': ['this is a definition', 'another definition', 'one final definition']})

print(df)
             definition   word
0  this is a definition   some
1    another definition  words
2  one final definition    yes
```

And then concatenating and splitting by space and using Counter

```
Counter(df.definition.str.cat(sep=' ').split())

Counter({'a': 1,
         'another': 1,
         'definition': 3,
         'final': 1,
         'is': 1,
         'one': 1,
         'this': 1})
```

Comment: Ted Petrou : thank you for the comment.
I would also like to know how to do the similar computation in the most pythonic way for say 1000 word definition?

Comment: This works for ant number of definitions of all different word sizes

Comment: I mean to say for 1000 different word  i.e 1000 row in the dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

I intend for this answer to be useful but not the chosen answer.  In fact, I'm only making an argument for `Counter` and @TedPetrou's answer.

***create large example of random words***

```
a = np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), size=(100000, 5))

definitions = pd.Series(
    pd.DataFrame(a).sum(1).values.reshape(-1, 10).tolist()).str.join(' ')

definitions.head()

0    hmwnp okuat sexzr jsxhh bdoyc kdbas nkoov moek...
1    iiuot qnlgs xrmss jfwvw pmogp vkrvl bygit qqon...
2    ftcap ihuto ldxwo bvvch zuwpp bdagx okhtt lqmy...
3    uwmcs nhmxa qeomd ptlbg kggxr hpclc kwnix rlon...
4    npncx lnors gyomb dllsv hyayw xdynr ctwvh nsib...
dtype: object
```

***timing***
`Counter` is an order of `1000` times faster than fastest I could think of.

[image]